# Same view in Different States in Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What would be the most angularJS way to go about using the same view contained in different states but not positioned in the same spot on the page.
So for example, if I have :

```
app.config( function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
           .state({
                  name : 'view1'   ,
                  url: '/'         ,
                  views:{
                       'view1_child1' : {templateUrl : "../src/template1.html  },
                       'view1_child2' : {templateUrl : "../src/template2.html  },
                         }
                })
           .state({
                  name : 'view2' ,
                  url: '/index.html'       ,
                  views:{
                       'view2_child3' : {templateUrl : "../src/template3.html  },
                       'view2_child4' : {templateUrl : "../src/template4.html  },
                      'view2_child1' : {**templateUrl : "../src/template1.html**}
                        }
                })
    })
```

Notice template1.html is used in 2 different states. let say in the first state that div is placed centered of the screen, but in the different state it is placed on the right hand side.. What would be a more economical way (reuse of same code), simple but not too convoluted to do it the angularJS way?
thnks

Comment: Please, provide more information. What is going on in these views? Should they stay in sync? Is `{templateUrl : "../src/template1.html  }` not efficient enough?

Comment: template1.html is just an element, a partial. So it's not the entire page. for instance its a div , but it is placed into a certain portion of the page in  one state. now, how can i make it be in a different part of the page in a second state?

Comment: Well, `{templateUrl : "../src/template1.html }` looks like all you need in this case, unless you have other concerns.